# Direct calling from application

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to do a direct calling from my application. The labelfield contains a phone number, how do I do a direct call from there? When the user selects the phone number in the labelfield and clicks the green button, it will automatically call the number. Please explain step by step if you don't mind. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
String phoneNumber = "555234324"; //the number that you wanna call
PhoneArguments call = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, phoneNumber);
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, call);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Phone](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/Phone.html) class description. It is easy to understand how to use it.

Comment: okay, but if i were to link that all to a labelfield, it is possible right?

Comment: You can get labelfield contents via labelfield.getText(). And pass this text (phone number) to the Phone class instance to make a call.